# Better to return None or throw an exception when fetching URL?

Tags: scala, exception, throw, idioms, scala-option

I have a Scala helper method that currently tries to fetch a URL and return an Option[String] with the HTML of that webpage.

If there are any exceptions (malformed url, read timeouts, etc...) or if there are any problems it returns a None. The question is, would it be better to just throw the exception so the calling code can log the exception or is it preferable to return the None in this case?

Comment: If it's a helper method, I assume it is private. If it is private, then you are the caller. If you are the caller, then you are the one who has all the information about what should happen, so do whatever you want. Otherwise see Jean's answer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Creating exceptions is expensive because the stack trace has to be filled. Throwing and catching exceptions is also more expensive than a normal return. Considering that, you might ask yourself the following questions:

- **Do you want to force handling of an error by the caller?** If so, don't throw an exception, as Scala has no checked-exception mechanism that forces the caller to catch them.
- **In case of an error, do you want to include details on why it failed?** If not, you can just return `Option[A]`, where `A` is your return type, and then you'd either have `Some(validContent)` or `None`, with no additional explanation. If yes, you can return something like `Either[E, A]` or a Scalaz `Validation[E, A]`. All of this options force the caller to somehow unwrap the result while being free to process the error `E` as he wants. Now what should `E` be?
- **Do you want to provide a stack trace in case of failure?** If so, you *could* return `Either[Exception, A]` or `Validation[Exception, A]`. If you really go with the exception, you'll want to use `Try[A]`, whose two possible cases are `Failure(exc: Throwable)` and `Success(value: A)`. Note that you will of course incur the costs of creating the throwable. If not, you can maybe just return `Either[String, A]` (and be extra careful to remember whether `Right` means success or failure here — `Left` is usually used for errors, and `Right` for the “right” value — `Validation` is maybe clearer). If you want to *optionally* return a stack trace, you could use Lift's `Box[A]`, which could be `Full(validContents)`, `Empty` with no additional explanation (very similar to `Option[A]` up to here), or indicate a `Failure` which can store an error string and/or a throwable (and more).
- **Do you maybe want to provide multiple indications as to why it failed?** Then return `Either[Seq[String], A]`. If you do this frequently, you may probably want to use Scalaz and a `Validation[NonEmptyList[String], A]` instead, which provides some other nice goodies. Look it up for more info about it or check out [these usage examples](http://johnkurkowski.com/posts/accumulating-multiple-failures-in-a-ValidationNEL/).

Comment: Great summary! Personally, I use Either[String,...] most of the time,  Scalaz's Validation seems clearer though.

Answer (score 1):

I think that in this case, if is important to log the exceptions then by all means throw the exceptions (and possibly just return String instead of the option). Otherwise you might as well just return the None. One warning- there may be exceptions for other reasons that you don't foresee, in which case it may be dangerous to make a catch-all bit of code.

One thing that you could do is something like Lift's `Box` system. A Box is essentially an Option, but with a couple features added in: A `Full` is like a `Some`, an `Empty` is like a `None`, but Lift goes a step further and has a `Failure`, which is like an `Empty` but with a reason/message.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule of thumb is "if you can handle the exception, handle it". So there's not enough context to guess. You can use the tryFetchUrl/fetchUrl pair of methods.